ValueError: The layer sequential_7 has never been called and thus has no defined input
when I run the following code:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def visualize_feature_maps(model_path, image_path, layer_name='conv2d'):

  model = load_model(model_path)

  conv_layer = model.get_layer(layer_name)

  intermediate_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=conv_layer.output)

  img = Image.open(image_path)
  img = tf.image.resize(img, [128,128], antialias=True)
  img_array = np.array(img)

  activations = intermediate_model.predict(img_array[np.newaxis, ...])

  fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 4, figsize=(10, 10))
  for i in range(16):
      ax = axs[i // 4, i % 4]
      ax.imshow(activations[0, :, :, i], cmap='gray')
      ax.axis('off')
  plt.show()


model_path = r'C:\Users\gabri\OneDrive - ufu.br\TCC\VS Code\Models\Model ESTE.keras'
image_path = r'C:\Users\gabri\OneDrive - ufu.br\TCC\VS Code\Dataset\Diabrotica speciosa\diabroticaspeciosa (1).jpg'

model = load_model(model_path)
visualize_feature_maps(model_path, image_path)

I get the error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 33
     30 image_path = r'C:\Users\gabri\OneDrive - ufu.br\TCC\VS Code\Dataset\Diabrotica speciosa\diabroticaspeciosa (1).jpg'
     32 model = load_model(model_path)
---> 33 visualize_feature_maps(model_path, image_path)

Cell In[30], line 13
      9 model = load_model(model_path)
     11 conv_layer = model.get_layer(layer_name)
---> 13 intermediate_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=conv_layer.output)
     15 img = Image.open(image_path)
     16 img = tf.image.resize(img, [128,128], antialias=True)

The code loads a saved model and should display the output of the first convolutional layer. The model cannot be retrained as it is a model already in use that needs to be documented. I tried to use Gemini to fix it, but your suggestion is to retrain the model
TensorFlow version: 2.17.0
Keras version: 3.4.1
Python version: 3.11.9

When a model is loaded, its layers exist in an undefined input shapes. To initialize a model's layers with defined input shapes, you must feed it with actual input data, such as an image.
